# How to crop DICOM images

Tags: c#, dicom

I want to crop a DICOM image from the top. I am very new in handling DICOM. Can anybody suggest me how can I do this in C#/.NET ?

As a side note, also suggest me an open source library available to do it or if possible the way I can do it. The goal is to crop the DICOM Series (image by image) and then save it as a new Series.

Comment: You will probably need a combination of libraries. For example, if you are working in WPF you could use [fo-dicom](https://github.com/rcd/fo-dicom) to obtain a bitmap of the DICOM image and [WriteableBitmapEx](https://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) to manipulate it. Both libraries are easily incorporated in your code via NuGet.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson I have the dicom image series and again I have to save it in dicom series format after cropping it.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of way for doing this. Maybe the easiest is to install CTN. On a typical debian system:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ctn
$ dcm_resize -c 256 -r 256 -t -v in.dcm out.dcm
```

I believe imagemagick `convert` also supports DICOM files.

If you really want to do it directly from C#, you can use GDCM/C# binding, and check out the following two examples on how to manipulate a DICOM image buffer:

1. [BasicImageAnonymizer](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/BasicImageAnonymizer_8cs-example.html)
2. [ExtractImageRegion](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/ExtractImageRegion_8cs-example.html)